# Sympy can not plot float probability with factorial

Tags: sympy

This is the raw code, and I want to plot some probability functions. But it does not work, anyone knows what's going wrong?

Thank you guys!!!

```py
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
from sympy.plotting import plot

init_printing()

def f(x):
    return (factorial(365) / factorial(365 - x )).evalf() / (365**x)

display(f(5))
x = symbols('x')
plot(f(x),(x,0,100),ylim=[0,2])
```

Result I got

```
0.972864426300206 
      1 |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
      0 |-------------------------------------------------------
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
        |                                                       
     -1 |_______________________________________________________
         0                          50                         100
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```py
>>> plot((factorial(365) / factorial(365 - x ))/ (365**x),(x,0,100))
```

I get
[image]

Evaluation with the factorial doesn't seem to work, but using `rf` or `ff` does:

```py
def f(x):
    return (ff(365, x)/(365**x)).n(3)

plot(f(x), (x, 0, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: With your implementation, I got: `OverflowError: int too large to convert to float`

Comment: ```File <lambdifygenerated-1>:2, in _lambdifygenerated(x)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(x):
----> 2     return 2510412867555873229292944374881202770516552026987607976687259519390110613822093741966601800900025416937617231436098232866070807112336997985344536791065387238359970435553274093767809149142944086431604692507451013484702554601409800590796554104119549610531188617337343514551719328276084775588229169021353912347918627470151939680850494072260703300124632839880055048742799987669041697343786107818534466796687151104965388813013683```

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/math/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/math/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from sympy) (1.2.1)

Comment: Did you try it without the `evalf`?

Comment: Yes, by coping with your code.

Comment: See updated answer which uses `ff` successfully with evaluation.

Comment: still OverflowError: int too large to convert to float, I think it might be M1 problem, going to try on another ubuntu instance.

Comment: Your second method worked in another sympy==1.5.1 version ubuntu computer, still overflow for the first one. But in my m1 both failed.